# Show price BETWEEN two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I see so many examples how to do this but in my case does not work. My app is for renta car. I have two table

first is for campaign season.

**season:**

```
ID    Start_date      End _date        Name
-------------------------------------------------------
1    2016-05-01      2016-08-31        seasonal price
2    2016-09-01      2017-04-31        non seasonal price
```

**season_prices**

```
    ID    Price  ID_Season     ID_Car
------  ------  ---------  -------------------
     1     150          1                1
     2     120          2                2
     3      70          1                3
     4      60          1                4
```

So when user select started date and end date show price based on date. Price has diferent value based on date.

I try

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `calculatePrice`$$
CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    PROCEDURE `rentacar_site`.`calculatePrice`(id_car INT,startDate DATE,endDate DATE)
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
    | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
    | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
    | COMMENT 'string'*/
    BEGIN
    SELECT a.name, s.name, c.price 
    FROM season_prices c
    INNER JOIN season s ON s.ID = c.ID
    INNER JOIN car a  ON a.ID = c.ID_Car
    WHERE a.ID = id_car AND startDate AND ebdDate BETWEEN s.Start_Date AND s.End_Date ;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

WHen i call 
`CALL calculatePrice(1, '2016-01-05', '2016-08-31');`
He return me true, car with that season name and price. But when i set `CALL calculatePrice(1, '2016-10-05', '2016-20-05');` all time returb NULL

What i do wrong ?

Comment: What does it mean? `2016-20-05` There's no that date.

Comment: `AND startDate AND ebdDate BETWEEN s.Start_Date AND s.End_Date` doesn't really make sense (and there is a typo in here).

Comment: @User that date select customer. Example am customer and i want to take car. App say "Please select started date and return date" based on date i show diferent prace. Lets season start 01.05.2016 - 01.09.2016 have own price,  and if date between that two dates show me that price

Comment: @X.L.Ant not a mysql expert here, but does mysql treat `..and columnname..` as true if columnname is not null? I'm guessing that's what's happeniing here with `..and col1 and col2 between...`

Comment: @Zend I mean you first write something like '2016-08-31' what means for me that on the last position is day, but then you write '2016-20-05' what doesn't make sense for me, because there's no 20th month.

Comment: Ah i see i change position of day to month. THe correct date is `2016-05-20`   YY-DD-MM

Comment: The prices are per day? And for a period from 2016-08-30 till 2016-09-02, you'd want to calculate total price = 2 x low price + 2 x high price? Or what else?

Comment: example : The price for period 01.05.2016 till 31.08.2016 has 150$ price and that is season price. Un season price for period 01.09.2016 till 30.04.2017 has 100$. The price is static and is not for per day

Comment: Yes, that's in the table. I am asking if this season price is a price per day. Moreover for *one* date, say 20.05.2016, I can tell you the season price (it's in the period 01.05.2016 till 31.08.2016, so for car # 1 it's 150). But your function accepts *two* dates, startDate and EndDate, so what result would you expect for a range from 2016-08-30 till 2016-09-02, with two days in period 1 and two in period 2? This is what I am asking.

Comment: Only what i expect is to return Price from `season_prices` based on date. Sry for my bad english

Comment: @X.L.Ant what do you think? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84974/1/0

Comment: But you don't have *a* date. You have a start date and an and date, i.e. a date *range*. So again: What result do you expect for startdate = 2016-08-30 and enddate = 2016-09-02?

Comment: for startdate = 2016-08-30 and enddate = 2016-09-02 i expect to return `non season prices`

Comment: @artm ok, thanks for the insights :)

Comment: @X.L.Ant Same fiddle gives an error on mssql so yeah another mysql thing to be aware of I guess. It looks like OP is ignoring this convo between us but I think you are right with your first comment. When the `between` part of the query doesn't find a value it's false, otherwise true so it's included in the result.

Comment: So the rule is: give us the price for the enddate (and ignore the startdate altogether). Correct?

Comment: I dont have price for end date and i dont need it. I have only two prices. First `( January, February . March, Apr, May) = 150$ ` second price `June, July, August,  September, October, , November, Dec = 100$` idk what is problem to understand. If now is May than show price 150$ else if now November show 100$ price

Comment: Yes I understand how to get the price for *one* date. But your function asks for *two* dates, namely startDate and endDate. I ask you what to return for startDate = 2016-08-30 and endDate = 2016-09-02 and you say 'non season prices'. So you ignored the startDate and told me the price for the EndDate. Or by what other rule did you decide for 'non season prices'?

Comment: What's the data type of `StartDate` and `EndDate`